# unusual - vba error: object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

Now I'm aware that many issues with this error have been asked and answered in the past but this case is slightly stanger and I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

I've written some code that searches through excel files for a keyword and then returns information on where it found the keyword. The code works fine for most keywords I enter but there are certain ones that when I run the macro it produces the 91 error message. If anyone can figure out why that would be awesome!

Code is:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim strSearch As String ' Keyword to search for
Dim strPath As String ' Filepath of folder to search
Dim strFile As String ' current file that the loop is searching through
Dim wOut As Worksheet ' Worksheet to display results
Dim wbk As Workbook ' Workbook to be searched
Dim wks As Worksheet ' Worksheet to be searched
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change as desired
strPath = "\\ant\dept-eu\LTN1\Techies Information\aa Eng daily log"
strSearch = InputBox("Insert Keyword to search")

Set wOut = Sheet1
lRow = 1
With wOut
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Text in Cell"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
          (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
          UpdateLinks:=0, _
          ReadOnly:=True, _
          AddToMRU:=False)

        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets ' for each worksheet
            Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch) ' setting variable to first result in find function
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then ' if something is found
                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address ' set first address to that cell's address
            End If
            Do
                If rFound Is Nothing Then ' if nothing was found
                    Exit Do ' exit loop
                Else ' if something was found then add the details to the table
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                    .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Value
                End If
               Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)  ' sets rfound vaiable to next found value
            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address ' once the find function gets back to the first address then exit the loop

        Next ' next worksheet in file

        wbk.Close (False)
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
Set wOut = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set wbk = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
```

The Error occurs on the  Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address line

Comment: That error means your `rFound` is set to Nothing, because it couldn't find `strSearch`.  You'll need to change the placement of your error checking.

Comment: Thanks! I've now added an If rFound is Nothing then exit do statement and it seems to now work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your code enters the `Do` loop even when nothing is found.

Try something like:

```
Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(what:=strSearch, lookat:=xlWhole, lookin:=xlValues) 
If Not rFound Is Nothing Then 
    strFirstAddress = rFound.Address 
    Do
        lRow = lRow + 1
        .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
        .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
        .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Value
        Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound) 
    Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address 
End If
```

It's a good idea to specify the additional arguments to `Find()`, since their values will persist between uses (even from a use via the Excel UI) so you can never rely on what values will be used if you omit them.

Comment: Thanks, I've tidied up the code but I'm still having the same problem. For example when searching for word "controller" the code works fine, searching through every file in the folder and reporting all of the instances. However, searching other works like "conveyor" causes the macro to produce the 91 error after searching through the first workbook.

Comment: I would create a new question with the current code and indicate where the error occurs.